# Apache htaccess rules

Tags: .htaccess

I am currently trying to rewrite two urls, i need to use rewrite rules as I need the rules to be domain specific as multiple sites are sharing the same htaccess file.

Can anyone see why I am getting the following issues below?

```
RewriteRule ^wp/blog/$ http://domain.co.uk/blog/ [L,R=301]
```

is currently giving me /blog/blog instead of just blog

Also:

```
RewriteRule ^sb-lookbook$ http://domain.co.uk/lookbook/ [L,R=301]
```

Just goes to /sb-lookbook still.

Comment: Have you checked whether your mod_rewrite module is enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the RewriteBase? That might solve your problem.